# In VS code how to warn if import name clashes in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

While developing I used

```
from pydantic import ValidationError
.
.
.
from jsonschema.exceptions import ValidationError
```

I used the first imports but further I added another second import which resulted in not catching the expected result .but vscode did not throw any error notifying about the duplicate import or something as such.

As a result I was not able to catch the expected error as the actual one was over written.

Is there a way in vscode where it will give a squilly or some warning to notify that this current import is used or over written ?

Comment: First of all, put all your imports at the begining of your script. That is a convention followed by many developers and it makes it way easier to know which module is used.

Comment: It was place at the top but during developement I added the different import with same error. which lead to a bug which was difficult  to find

Comment: That's why it's recommended to follow style guidelines (like [PEP008](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) there's an exemple at the and of the section regarding names clashes)

Comment: agreed. but mistakes happen . is there way to get some kind of warning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get warnings through **[Linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)**, now you can still enable it with the following settings

```
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
```

But it is better to install the linting extension(such as [**Pylint**](https://such%20as%20pylint)), because this is what Microsoft recommends.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) has a rule that warns you about redifinition.

Considering `toto.py`

```
from pydantic import ValidationError
from jsonschema.exceptions import ValidationError
```

Using flake8 via command line:

```
$ flake8 toto.py
toto.py:2:1: F811 redefinition of unused 'ValidationError' from line 1
```

If you absolutely need it within VSCode, there is an
[extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8) for it:

[image]